# Sitefinity: Where can I find the master GUID for a content item?

Tags: telerik, sitefinity

I'm building a web service for a client that pulls data from the Sitefinity CMS.  The problem is they want to pass in a Guid for the service and receive the info about this item.  No problem except I only have been able to locate the "live" Guid for one Item (and that was by combing through the HTML in the back end).

I was going to look at the tables in SQL Server but I'm not sure which table to look at.  The content items have several tables all related of course and there isn't any documentation on how to look at this.  I can find plenty of documentation on querying the master Guid, but no place to find it.

Oh, and these are custom content types built by the Module Builder.

Any Help would be SOOOOO appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var master = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager().Lifecycle.GetMaster(<liveGuidHere>);
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the biggest consumers of Sitefinity webservices is Sitefinity. The best place to start looking for that guid is to take a look at what web service calls are being made when you pull up your custom content item list in the backend. I used the chrome developer tools and check in the network tab.

One I found for a stores module made with module builder was something to the effect of http://www.testsite.com/Sitefinity/Services/DynamicModules/Data.svc/?managerType=Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicModules.DynamicModuleManager&providerName=OpenAccessProvider&itemType=Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Stores.Store&provider=OpenAccessProvider&sortExpression=LastModified%20DESC&skip=0&take=50

The json this returns is a list of all the masters with their ids (note in the list that the content items all have have a status of 0) http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/developers-guide/sitefinity-essentials/modules/content-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

When you go to Administration / Module Builder / Your Module, you will see a link to the API on the top right corner.

This link goes to a page full of API examples for *your particular module* which is kind of cool.

Basically you would have to find your item first using LINQ and the GetValue extension method.
Once you have the item you can get its ID or any other property.

```
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Utilities.TypeConverters;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicModules;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Model;
....
var mgr = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager();
var countrymasters = from ctry in mgr.GetDataItems(TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Destinations.Destination"))
                                 where ctry.GetValue<string>("culture") == siteid &&
                                 (ctry.Status == Telerik.Sitefinity.GenericContent.Model.ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && ctry.Visible == true)
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     airport_cd = ctry.GetValue<string>("airport_cd"),
                                     country_master_cd = ctry.GetValue<string>("country_master_cd")
                                 };
```

Comment: Yes, I know about this.  My problem that I'm running into is that this is a custom module and I'm trying to get info for a sub module's content.

Comment: The tables used by the Dynamic Module Builder are sf_dynamic_content and depending on the name of your module could be something like Flights_Flight or Destinations_Destination.
Note, they are missing the sf_ prefix so make sure to search them at the top of the Tables tree in SQL Management Studio :)

They are joined by the base_id column.

There are other related tables as well, e.g. for the Language Data (sf_language_data) + some other, but those two above are probably what you are looking for.